# start Express in AWS EC2 without root is not reachable

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-ec2

I have deployed an Express application into EC2 instance but there is a weird problem. After SSH into the instance, If I start the server by

```
node server.js
```

it is not available through the browser;

If I start the server by

```
sudo node server.js
```

everything is ok.

Not suer why.

Comment: What port is your application listening on?
Are you using a web server of any kind to route your communication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ports less than 1024 are reserved for root, and thus require root permission.**

My guess is that you are attempting to bind to ports 80/443, the default web ports. As such, this requires root permissions.

However, it is a ***bad idea*** to run your application as root, and so an alternative solution should be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

sudo permission is required on low number port. you should use a proxy in front of your app; like nginx so that you can use low number port by redirect to your app's port.